# Changing content of webpage

Tags: c#, browser, html, dom

I have a web page with some content and a button `Save`. Through my C# code I want to change content of the webpage and then Click Save button. Here is my code.

```
string replace = webBrowser1.DocumentText.Replace("2013.0.0.1", "2013.0.0.2");
webBrowser1.DocumentText = replace;

links = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
{
    if ((link.GetAttribute("Name") == "Save"))
    {
        if (link.GetAttribute("type").Equals("submit"))
        {
            link.InvokeMember("click");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

My website does not save anything when clicking save. It does not even navigate to the page where it should after clicking Save button.

I noticed one strange thing. When I remove the first 3 lines to replace text and then change the content manually, everything works fine. Webpage saves content and navigates to proper location.

Any ideas to get a workaround?

Comment: "does not work" is very uninformative. How does it "not work"?

Comment: I guess my whole sentence goes as `And the above code does not work and my website does not save anything on clicking save. And not even navigate to page where it should, after clicking Save button.`.....this is the way it does not work. Please let me know if you are looking for some information that I am missing

Comment: I took the liberty to clean up your statement. I removed the redundant parts and added some line breaks. To me, that reads more clearly.

Comment: Ohh....thats all right. Whatever fits the viewers is good to go from my side :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately I got it. I realized my approach was not correct. I got all my text from `HTML` and then was trying to replace a text in that. I noticed later that the text was present in a `textarea`. So I fetched the text of that textarea and then replaced the text. Then hitting `Save` was working fine. Here is my code:

```
HtmlElementCollection links = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("A");

links = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("textarea");
foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
{
    if ((link.GetAttribute("Name") == "text"))
    {
        string attribute = link.InnerText;
        string replace = attribute.Replace(@"Hello World", @"Helo World!!!");
        link.InnerText = replace;
        break;
    }
}

links = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
{
    if ((link.GetAttribute("Name") == "Save"))
    {
        if (link.GetAttribute("type").Equals("submit"))
        {
            link.InvokeMember("click");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.